# Cache Access Denied-eclipse-emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, caching, proxy, emulation

When trying to run a simple webView application on eclipse with a computer with proxy internet access the emulator (nexus s) displays "error cache access denied" and below that "sorry you are not currently allowed to request http://google.it/ from this chache until you have authenticated yourself. The emulator's APN is set to the correct proxy and port  as well as username and password and the internet works on the emulator.

The Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

       String url = "http://www.google.it";
   WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   view.loadUrl(url);  
} 

   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your current android virtual device and create a new one. This solved my error.

Comment: or install HAXM accelerator using SDK Manager.